# Configure maven on eclipse to use with android 4.1.2

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

Has anyone ever successfully configured Maven on eclipse to develop android apps? May I have your notes on how you did it?

I am using ubuntu Natty Narwha, eclipse juno, Android 4.1.2.

I tried using the notes on the following link to no avail: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/EclipseIntegration

Specific error:

When I create a skeleton android-project per the tutorial http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/, I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
```

I get the same error if I change to `android-14`, which is the version of my platform-tools

Comment: Could you be more explicit about where you're setting 'android-10'? Have you updated your SDK recently?

Comment: @Ricardo Gladwell, have you looked at the links? The tutorial I mention (http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) has three short sections. Section 3 step 6 has the details. Also, I have the latest everything; I just installed android (and upgraded).

Comment: Have you downloaded android-10 and android-14 in Android SDK manager?

Comment: @androfactured I have read them, in fact I wrote one of them. but that doesn't help me identify where you are getting the error message from. Are you setting an installed android in your project.properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a solution but an explanation. So after @Ricardo Gladwell's insistence that the tutorial is correct, I decided to try it on a Mac. As it turned out everything worked on the mac. That's when I figured my Ubuntu install had a lot more problems than that.

In conclusion the tutorial works, and my computer is not working.

Thanks, @Ricardo Gladwell.